# Not able to use crystal report with mvc 5 visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

searched every where and lot's of sites, but I have users data and selects and search based on user identity and roles so I need to pass data to report file from the controllers and I want to try crystal report but not available in 2015 VS
-- I tryied , modifying Visual Studio and added web tools and sql tools but still same problem I don't see any crystal report menu in new item---

### any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

U can use visual studio report wizard of Crystal report. I think it may help

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/66489a/report-wizard-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: but for dynamic content it's very difficult to manage in controller with users and roles for implementing it requires lot's of skill I need simple crystal report and some basics