# visual studio 2015, crystal report installed every thing but not showing in menu

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

visual studio 2015, installed the crystal report setup, but I am not able see in menu, when choosing new item in report section.

very best wishes for the person whom answers me really need it

### thanks

please check the previous questions they may not be solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to use crystal report with mvc 5 visual studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623759/not-able-to-use-crystal-report-with-mvc-5-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: You down voted, but there is no answer I think this how you are preventing the question to be answered

Answer (score 0):

In case if you installed incorrectly,

- Choosing right version for download.http://tektutorialshub.com/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2015/
- installation
  http://tektutorialshub.com/install-crystal-reports-visual-studio/

If installed correctly still facing issue then go to package manager and install Crystal report / Reporting.

Crystal Report installation for VS is steps:

- regular installing the software.
- installing CR from VS package manager.

GoodLuck :)